# How to scroll left column when cursor is above right column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

How to scroll up and down the left column when I'm scrolling over the map canvas?

Map has disabled scroll wheel propagation, it would be nice to accomplish it if possible only by CSS. I've tried to wrap `#map_canvas` by other div with flex property and set map to position absolute and 100vh/vw, but it doesn't make difference with wheel bubble.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var post = "<h3>Post title</h3><div>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</div><hr>";
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 10) { $('#left_container').append(post); i++; }

  var options = {
    zoom: 10,
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49, 17)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], options);

  $("#map_canvas").scrollLeft();
});
```

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}
.flexbox-container #left_container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
#map_canvas {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div id="left_container"></div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you still want the map to receive drag-drop, click, doubleclick events, or should the map be completely static?

Comment: I want cancel only zoom scroll event, other events should be available.

Comment: `$("#map_canvas").scrollLeft();` is a getter. It just returns an integer, maybe you wanted `$("#map_canvas").scrollLeft(0)` to scroll all the way to the left? In this context, even that is wrong, because you "scroll" in google maps by setting the `center` property. The earth is a sphere, there is no "start" position.

Comment: Does my answer solves your problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! I have only to adjust it to responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syzt0p17/7/)**

In this solution, I am assuming map is `200px` wide. You can replace it by another value in css and js.

You want to scroll the leftmost column when the mouse is hover the rightmost (map) column.
To accomplish this, the leftmost column should actually occupy **all** the viewport, although visually does not look like that.

In the `#left_container` below, you can see that is absolutely placed to fit all `.flexbox-container` parent boundaries. The trick part is the `border-right: 200px transparent solid` that "pushes" the vertical scroll bar to the left.

So, when you move your mouse wheel on the map, you are actually hovering the `#left_container`'s right border and thus moving it up and down, not the map.

```
.flexbox-container {
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
}

#left_container {
  padding: 0 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 200px transparent solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#left_container.scrollMap {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#map_canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

The above CSS solution, completely ignores other maps events (dblclick, click,...)
To fix that, we need a bit of JS to ignore mouse events on the leftmost column (see [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)):

```
  var map_canvas = $('#map_canvas')[0],
      $left_container = $('#left_container'),
      $parent = $('.flexbox-container'),
      options = {
          zoom: 10,
          scrollwheel: false,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(49, 17)
      },
      map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, options),
      wheelEvent = function (e) {
          $left_container.addClass('scrollMap');
      };

  map_canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel', wheelEvent);
  map_canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheelEvent);
  $parent.mousemove(function (e) {
    if (e.clientX < $parent.width() - 200) {
      $left_container.addClass('scrollMap');
    } else {
      $left_container.removeClass('scrollMap');
    }    
  });


<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div id="left_container" class="scrollMap"></div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to transfer the scroll event of a container `#canvas_container` to the left column by javascript. To accomplish this, the map has to be inside a container and padded at the top and bottom (`.padder` elements).

This way you can theoretically scroll up and down, catch this scroll event and transfer it to the left column. Other events are not touched.

The key part is this javascript:

```
  $canvas_container = $('#canvas_container')
  $left_container = $('#left_container');
  initial_offset = 100;

  $canvas_container.scrollTop(initial_offset);

  $canvas_container.on('scroll', function(e) {
    $left_container.scrollTop($left_container.scrollTop() + $canvas_container.scrollTop() - initial_offset);
    $canvas_container.scrollTop(initial_offset);
  });
```

Only drawback I see atm is the visible vertical scroll bar on the map.

To play around by yourself, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brp0ujmf/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var post = "<h3>Post title</h3><div>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</div><hr>";
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    $('#left_container').append(post);
    i++;
  }

  var options = {
    zoom: 10,
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49, 17)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], options);


  $canvas_container = $('#canvas_container')
  $left_container = $('#left_container');
  initial_offset = 100; // same as height of .padder

  $canvas_container.scrollTop(initial_offset);

  $canvas_container.on('scroll', function(e) {
    $left_container.scrollTop($left_container.scrollTop() + $canvas_container.scrollTop() - initial_offset);
    $canvas_container.scrollTop(initial_offset);
  });

});
```

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 80vh;
}
.flexbox-container #left_container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 80vh;
}
#canvas_container {
  flex: 2;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
.padder {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div id="left_container"></div>
  <div id="canvas_container">
    <div class="padder"></div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div class="padder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```